# How to push docker auto build image to AWS instance with a hook?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerhub

I have a Dockerhub account linked with Github which is auto build. With every action on Github , a build is started on dockerhub account. but now, I have to find a way through which AWS can listen the new build and take a pull of this build and run it.

I am new to docker skills, Please let me know if any one know the solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Webhook feature in DockerHub to link with a CI/CD tool to trigger the docker pull in your EC2 instance. For example using Jenkins

- Setup Jenkins in a EC2 instance or on-premise
- Remote SSH to the EC2 instance using Jenkins Remote SSH plugin
- Create a Build Job for Deployment
- Inside the Job, add shell script code to pull the image from DockerHub.
- To trigger the job, register a webhook linked with the Jenkins Job, inside DockerHub Webhooks section as a build trigger to invoke the webhook.

Comment: I have started GITHUB integration with Docker hub but when I am trying to create a pull 'FROM' base image through Dockerfile, It is showing me an error of 'unauthorized: authentication required' from base, I have credentials to login to base, Can I Pass credentials in FROM of Dockerfile with URL .

Comment: To access your private repositories, you need to authenticate docker hub. Check the following https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store